# How do I escape special characters when using ServiceStack OrmLite with SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have a piece of code where we try to match a pattern against the data in the database.

We use ServiceStack.OrmLite against our SQLite DB.

So for example, given the below records:

```
ColA    ColB
-----   ---------
ABC     ABC_Long
GHI     GHI_Long
GHIP    GHIP_Long
```

We use a predicate as:

```
var result = db.Select(x => x.ColA.StartsWith("GHI_"));
```

Everything works fine until we have a search pattern that includes an SQL special character such as '%' or '_' so for example given the search pattern of "GHI_":

The expected row should be:

```
GHI     GHI_Long
```

However we get:

```
GHI     GHI_Long
GHIP    GHIP_Long
```

Which is due to ORMLite not escaping the special character and generating the below SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE UPPER(colA) LIKE 'GHI_%' OR UPPER(colB) LIKE 'GHI_%';
```

Instead of the correctly escaped version which should be:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE UPPER(colA) LIKE 'GHI\_%' OR UPPER(colB) LIKE 'GHI\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Can you think of a way to address this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added implicit support for [escaping wildcards in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/5016868b5f7f1c12ef580223926fd386e2f54e06) which will now escape wildcards in the typed expressions that make use of `LIKE`, namely `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `Contains`, e.g:

```
using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<Poco>();

    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "ab" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a_c" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a_cd" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "abcd" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a%" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a%b" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a%bc" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a\\" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a\\b" });
    db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "a\\bc" });

    Assert.That(db.Count<Poco>(q => q.Name == "a_"), Is.EqualTo(0));
    Assert.That(db.Count<Poco>(q => q.Name.StartsWith("a_")), Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(db.Count<Poco>(q => q.Name.StartsWith("a%")), Is.EqualTo(3));
    Assert.That(db.Count<Poco>(q => q.Name.StartsWith("a_c")), Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(db.Count<Poco>(q => q.Name.StartsWith("a\\")), Is.EqualTo(3));
    Assert.That(db.Count<Poco>(q => q.Name.StartsWith("a\\b")), Is.EqualTo(2));
}
```

This will be available in **v4.0.19** which is [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for the super fast response.

Comment: @mythz, are there any plans of exposing api to make like requests without "upper" function? I need this to optimize sql server request with index seek, which is not an option with "upper".

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev I'll probably have to make this opt-in configurable as changing it would be a breaking change.

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev ok just added support for `OrmLiteConfig.StripUpperInLike` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d6e8e74cc29eabbf9b671e36cd47846b961db337). Note: using `upper()` provides consistent behavior across different DB providers as they can have different case-sensitive behavior for `LIKE` that's also subject to external on Environment settings.

Answer (score 2):

OrmLite does not have this built in but it does allow you to easy provide the correct SQL when you need it. You can simply do something like this:

```
var notes = db.Select<NoteDto>(" upper(\"NoteText\") like 'GHI@_%' ESCAPE '@' ");
```

In this manner you only have to write the where clause and you still get the benifits of the DTO auto population.

I changed the escape character just for clarity and to demonstrate it can be anything in SQLite.

Comment: thanks for the answer, we avoid writing direct SQL and instead create predicates which OrmLite then converts to SQL queries, so we would have a method which returns an Expression<Func<NoteDto, bool>> so we would very much like to have a solution around the existing usage of predicates